# I had to make a logo in 1 day with no brief, can you guys critique my work?

Tags: logo, critique

The client said they need a logo for a company called "WAVWY" which is going to launch a relationship activity sort of card game. For now, they needed a logo which looked fun and matched the product description and they needed it in a day. I had received no other information.
So I made a few variations and finalized 1, what do you guys think how can i make it better?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I can see the logic.. but it's entirely illegible.

Comment: I agree. It's not readable.  Also why does that poor child have no mouth.

Comment: This solution does not look "fun" at all, you can't read it, so it is very confusing.